# PINGing using Multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, ping, wifi

I'm using threads (here inly two for checking purpose) to Ping the first 8 devices on my connected network.

```
public void testThread1()
    {
        // executing in thread
        lstLocal.FullRowSelect = true;
        bool value;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {

            string ping_var = "192.168.1" + "." + i;
            value = Ping(ping_var, 4, 4);
            if (value == true)
            {
                ListViewItem items = new ListViewItem(ping_var.ToString());
                lstLocal.Items.Add(items);
            }


        }
        return;

    }
```

And the thread is called from

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        lstLocal.Items.Clear();
        lstLocal.View = View.Details;
        ThreadStart threaddelegate1 = new ThreadStart(new Form1().testThread1);

        //Calls Ping() with the same prameters as Thread1 but for next 4 devices
        ThreadStart threaddelegate2 = new ThreadStart(new Form1().testThread2);


        Thread newthread = new Thread(threaddelegate1);
        newthread[0] = new Thread(threaddelegate1);
        newthread[1] = new Thread(threaddelegate2);
        foreach (Thread mythread in newthread)
          {
             newthread.Start();


         }
    }
```

The first 4 devices are PINGed by thread1 and last four by thread2.The same function Ping() when called without threads works for me but causes delay(so thread approach).

What is the reason for it?I debugged and found that the thread is not executed and the application exits out of `Form1_Load()`.

Comment: I'm unsure about your question. Do you want to know why the ping requests makes your application freeze when you run it in your main thread?

Comment: the code above by me uses `listView` and on running the application I see no data on it.It means the thread is not performing duty

Comment: 1) I'd rather avoid threads in favour of asynchronous API calls. 2) You can't access the UI from other threads.

Comment: Is the above approach suitable in winforms? Am i missing pre-requisites for `newthread.start()`.Am new to this platform

Comment: @CodesInChaos so what's your suggestion to Ping x.x.x.0 to x.x.x.254 without using threads?

Comment: I just had PINGed without using threads and resulted in a notorious PING error `PROCESS_HAS_LOCKED_PAGES`

Comment: Something like `Ping.SendPingAsync`. In C# 5 you can simply `await` the result. In C# 4 you probably need to explicitly add a continuation scheduled on the main thread.

Comment: Why not use a background worker and use the reportprogress handler to add the item to the list view? Threads are not allowed to invoke the UI unless you explicitly tell them to. While doing the ping in  your main thread will freeze your application. And if it takes more then a minute or so cause a deadlock warning. Microsoft has a tutorial how to use background workers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry.I'm new. which one is better `Ping.SendAsnc()` or  background worker coz i have to Ping all my network IP's.

Comment: you mean mythread.Start

Comment: @Khan Just use the asynchronous version.  Pinging is an inherently asynchronous operation.  Using a thread or a background worker is performing an asynchronous operation and then creating a thread that will do nothing but sit there and wait for it to finish.  There's simply no reason to waste the effort to create such a thread when it never needs to actually *do* anything.

Comment: YES,i have done it using `SendAsync` method

Comment: But still the issues are there.1).Ping is unreliable 2).It doesn't have any defined number of attempts/time out (as used in async method)

Comment: @Khan It does expose a timeout; if you want to make multiple attempts then simply call the method however many times in a loop.

Comment: But won't it make things slow.Isn't there a fast & reliable method to do so?@Servy

Comment: @Khan It would be no slower or less reliable than using the synchronous version of the method.

Answer (score 1):

The threads are starting, but they don't do any work before you exit `Form.Load`. And then when they *do* work, you're trying to modify the UI from a non-UI thread, which will throw an exception in the thread.

If you want to modify the UI, you have to synchronize with the UI thread. That's usually done with `Form.Invoke`. In your code, if you change this:

```
            ListViewItem items = new ListViewItem(ping_var.ToString());
            lstLocal.Items.Add(items);
```

To

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
{
    ListViewItem items = new ListViewItem(ping_var.ToString());
    lstLocal.Items.Add(items);
});
```

It should work for you. See [MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

By the way, you probably don't need two threads for this. It'll probably work fine with just one thread doing the pinging.

Comment: He doesn't need *any* additional threads to do the pining, he just needs use the asynchronous method, rather than the synchronous method.

Comment: @mischel taking two threads at start was just for testing purpose

Comment: @Mischel I was suggested by a lot of developers at SO that go for asycnhronous method rather than threads

Comment: @Servy: That's certainly another option, and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating threads just to sit there and wait for the network request to complete, just use one of the inherently asynchronous methods of the `Ping` class.  Your original code is also trying to update the UI from a non-UI thread, so you need to make sure not to do that in your asynchronous version either.

The use of `await` makes this very easy.  Among other things, it will automatically marshal the continuation of the asynchronous operation to be in the current context, which in this case is the UI thread, so you don't need to handle doing that yourself.

```
public async Task PingThings()
{
    // executing in thread
    lstLocal.FullRowSelect = true;
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
        .Select(i => new Ping().SendPingAsync("192.168.1" + "." + i));
    var replies = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    foreach (var reply in replies.Where(reply => reply.Status == IPStatus.Success))
        lstLocal.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(reply.Address.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: But one thing is stopping me from it and i.e I want to get hostnames out of these IP's

Comment: Any idea for it? @Servy